# Laravel 5, Sub-Domain routing, with optional parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

I’ve just started learning Laravel 5 and trying to create multilanguage web site and want to use different domains for the language so en.example.app points to English version, es.example.app to Spanish and so on. I use route groups and below is my code.

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}.example.app'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('index');
    });
    Route::get('test', function(){
        return view('index');
    });
});
```

It works fine for all domains except example.app. Unfortunately optional parameters {domain?} doesn’t work for subdomains, and I don’t want to duplicate routes like this.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
Route::get('test', function(){
    return view('index');
});

Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}.example.app'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('index');
    });
    Route::get('test', function(){
        return view('index');
    });
});
```

Could somebody please advise how to avoid this duplication?

Comment: if user access example.app what language he get english version or custom website with different display

Answer (score 5):

Thats becuase the `{domain}.example.app` requires a `.` before `example.app`.

You can remove the `.` and add contraint for `domain` parameter for it to have atmost 1 `.`

So the code will look like

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}example.app'], function($group) {
    Route::get('/', function ($domain) {
        //code
    }) ;
    // more routes

    foreach($group->getRoutes() as $route){
        $route->where('domain', '[a-z]+\.{0,1}');
    }

});
```

P.S. : I don't know whether my regex is correct or not.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a file named `app-routes.php` which contains all your routes and then in your actual `routes.php` file

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}.example.app'], function() {
    include('app-routes.php');
}); 

Route::group(['domain' => 'example.app'], function() {
    include('app-routes.php');
});
```

Comment: Great 1, but have you tried it? How to set the domain to some constant?

Comment: I tried this out but i wasnt able to link properly from example.app to subdomain.example.app... Any thoughts on this? @j-davis. I tried this {{URL::route('home', array('subdomain' => 'johndoe'))}}

Answer (score 3):

A *MiddleWare* helped me.

```
Route::group(array('middleware' => 'resolve_domain'), function () {
    Route::get('/', 'WhitePapersController@getHomepage');
});
```

And in *MiddleWare* -

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $params = explode('.', $request->getHost());
    $sub_domains = config('admin_configs.editions'); // Predefined sub-domain
    $edition = false;
    if(!empty($params[0]) && in_array($params[0], $sub_domains, true))  {
        $edition = $params[0];
    }
    define('DOMAIN_EDITION', $edition); // Set constant to be used.

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your options are either the route duplication or a server level redirect for HTTP requests without a subdomain.

The simple option is to just forward `example.app` to `www.example.app`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}.example.app'], function() {

}); 

Route::group(['domain' => 'example.app'], function() {

});
```

this pattern is good but if you want to use different language add localization file